# delete[] messes up my program. what's happening?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, counting

I'm trying to write a function that checks to see if a string has only uppercase letters and each letter in the string will have the same quantity.  i.e. AXXA is a valid string, but AXX is not.

My checkUpper function works fine. But my checkLetters function would only work the first time when my program runs.

When I got rid of the delete[]s before my function return, it will work all the time.  But I know it will cause a memory leak.

I just want to ask what's causing it to work only the first time?  and how come it works everytime after I remove the delete[]s?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;enter code here
string input;
int NumOfLetters;

//check if everything is uppercase;
bool checkUpper(string input){
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        if(!isupper(input[i])) return false;
    return true;
}

//check to see if there are the same number of runners for each team;
bool checkLetters(string input){
    char* Letters= new char[input.length()];//worst case, all letters are used once;
    NumOfLetters=0; //letter counter
    for(int i=0; i<input.length();i++){
        if(Letters[NumOfLetters]!=input[i]){
            Letters[NumOfLetters]=input[i]; //putting different letters in Letters
            NumOfLetters++;
        }
    }

    int *CountLetters= new int[NumOfLetters]; //used to count each letter

    for(int i=0; i<NumOfLetters;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<input.length();j++)
            if(Letters[i]==input[j])CountLetters[i]++; //counting each letter
    }

    for(int i=0; i<NumOfLetters;i++){
        if(CountLetters[i]!=CountLetters[0]){ //comparing number of each letters to the first one;
            delete[] Letters;
            delete[] CountLetters;
            return false;
        }
    }
    delete[] Letters;
    delete[] CountLetters;
    return true; 
}


int main(){
    while(true){
        cout<<"Enter a string of uppercase characters to indicate places(enter done to terminate):";
        cin>>input;
        if(input=="done") break;
        if(!checkUpper(input)){
            cout<<"Uppercase letters ONLY! try again.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if(!checkLetters(input)){
            cout<<"Each team must have the same number of runners! try again.\n";
            continue;
        }

        //to be filled;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read due to the poor formatting.  Also, why are you using `string` for string data, and `new char [ ]`?  Just use `std::string` for all string data.

Comment: Your code is incredible hard to read because of the lack of tab formatting. But it seems like both your `Letters` and `CountLetters` arrays start out uninitialized, which means this program has a very slim chance of working. Regarding your crash, `delete[]` is rarely the cause - the cause is usually prior code which writes outside the bounds of the array and corrupts memory.

Comment: Your code as posted does not even call `checkLetters()`.   Given your statement that the problem occurs in `checkLetters()` that is a positive sign that the code you have posted differs from the code that exhibits your problem.    Since problems with `delete` often stem from misbehaviour of other code (e.g. pointer molestation overwriting data structures used internally by `new` and `delete`) it is a fair bet that nobody can help you - finding problems in code they can't see is beyond abilities of most.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I'm new to programming.  The codes looked better on Dev C++, and all the tabs somehow are gone after I copy and pasted.  I changed the checkTeam function to checkLetters, sorry about that part. Imma edit the formatting too.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @L.Dai If you're new to programming, use `std::string` and use `std::vector`.  The requirements you've stated do not require any usage of `new[ ]` and `delete[ ]`.

Comment: In which way is the program failing the second time? A crash? Wrong result? What input are you using for the two executions of the program?

Comment: @L.Dai Take this as a learning lesson as to what you can do with C++:  http://ideone.com/Sy7lWL

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: His code indentation seems to be ok IMO. Why is his formatting bad? Except for that part after using namespace std

Comment: @ShreyansSheth The original post was edited at least 3 times.  You should have seen the original post.

Comment: Aaah I see. I'll try and rewrite his code for him meanwhile

Comment: The first loop in `checkLetters` doesn't make sense. The array starts off uninitialized but then you test the values in it. Also `new int[NumOfLetters]` is uninitialized.

Comment: He just crashed my terminal with an infinte loop....

Comment: @StillLearning I wrote a while loop so the program was suppose to keep asking the user to input a string and keep validating the string.  The program never crashed, but after the first entry, it no longer perform correct validation.  i.e.  AAAEEE is valid for the first time, if I enter it again it will be invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone's help!  I modified my code by initializing the dynamic arrays.  Now it works every time.  Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the problem from a quick glance, but a number of comments:

- Never write a naked `new` or `delete`.  At the *very* worse, use `std::make_unique` or similar.  However, for this application `std::string` and `std::vector` will be better.
- As noted in the comments, you are not initializing the contents of `CountOfLetters` to zero (`new` won't do it for you).
- The first loop in `checkLetters` (where you initialize `Letters`) needs to be a double loop.  (You are not checking that letter has never been seen before - just that it isn't an uninitialized value!)
- You should prefer to pass strings as const references.

Finally, `checkLetters` would be much better using a `std::map`:

```
    bool checkLetters(const std::string& input) {
        if (input.length() == 0)
           return true;  // Just in case no characters at all.
        std::map<char,int> counts;
        for (const char c : input) {
            // No point in running over the string twice.  Do it in one go.
            if (!std::upper(c)) return false;
            // If there is an entry in the map, increment it.  If not,
            // create it (with value zero), and then increment.
            counts[c]++;
        }
        // input[0] would blow up if the string is length zero and we hadn't checked above
        const int target = counts[input[0]];
        for (const auto& keyvalue : counts)
        {
            const int value = keyvalue.second;
            if (value != target)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify my codes to initialize right away.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I had misread the question to be "every letter in the input must have only one count". Here's my new answer:

I glanced through your code and rectified your mistakes. I basically re-wrote parts of your original code and made a simple `checkLetters` function. There is no need to use dynamic allocation at all, unless a particular situation asks for it. 
All you can do is maintain a `map<char,int>` which stores the count of each letters in the input. After interating through the input, we keep a variable `mustHaveCnt` which is the count every letter must have. Now, iterate through all the letters in the map and if the count exceeds the `mustHaveCnt` variable, you return false. Else, the answer is true.
Also, I have rewritten your condition for input. It terminates correctly when the input is *"done"*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//check if everything is uppercase;
bool checkUpper(string input){
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        if(!isupper(input[i])) return false;
    return true;
}

//Checks if the input has the same number of runners
//use must have the header file 'map' included, e.i write "#include <map>" at the top
bool checkLetters(string input){
    map<char,int> storeCnt;
    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
        storeCnt[input[i]]++; //Increment the count of each letter found
    int mustHaveCnt=storeCnt.begin()->second; //The second entry stores the count
    for(map<char,int>::iterator it= ++storeCnt.begin(); it!=storeCnt.end(); it++) //Iterate and check cnt
        if(it->second != mustHaveCnt)
            return false; //terminate here since the count does not match
    return true;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter a string of uppercase characters to indicate places(enter done to terminate):\n";
    string input; //Let's avoid global declaration, unless needed
    cin>>input;
    while(input.compare("done")!=0)
    {
        int flag=1;
        if(!checkUpper(input)){
            cout<<"Uppercase letters ONLY! try again.\n";
            flag=0;
        }
        if(flag && !checkLetters(input)){
            cout<<"Each team must have the same number of runners! try again.\n";
            flag=0;
        }
        if(flag)
            cout<<"Valid String!\n";
        cin>>input;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that uppercase letters are contiguous - and in fact they aren't.  Firstly, 'Z'-'A' is much greater than 25 on IBM mainframes that use EBCDIC.  Secondly, depending on the default locale, letters like Ü are very likely to return 'true' from 'isupper'  Also, global arrays?  really?  It's not thread safe, and there is no reason not to make it local.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? I'm using ASCII code conventions and looking at the question, he doesn't seem to be working with IBM mainframes or anything. EBCDIC. Are you even kidding me? C++ standard? I'm referring to ASCII conventions

Comment: Also, thread safe? An integer array of 26*4 bytes is going to cause major problems. yuhoo :/

Comment: You are assuming (unnecessarily) ASCII conventions.  The OP doesn't say what platform he is using, so it is always worth writing portable code unless there is a good reason to make it non-portable.  Even using ASCII, what about Ü?  (OK, that's not an ASCII character, but it's present on all my colleagues keyboards at work.)

Comment: The OP is clearly a beginner.  It's good to encourage good habits from the start.  *Why* is cnt global rather than local to checkLetters?  What benefit is there?  (And it *will* cause problems if he ports this to a multi-thread program, and two threads call checkLetters at once.

Comment: That's worse!  At least your original code worked with the two examples: "AXXA" => true, "AXX" => false.  Your new code will now return false for both.  (The second X will be found in the set and return false.)  Incidentally, in my view, the easy way to test for existence in a set/map is:
if (unq.count(input[i]) != 0)
YMMV

Comment: I'm so sorry I have grossly misread the question. `Each letter have the same quantity`. I thought that each letter must only be present once

Comment: However, I strongly disagree with SOME of your views. Hear me out. 1. 'Good programming habits' are quite subjective, believe it or not. You use different conventions on IBM mainframes and different ones on home conventions. If the OP is a beginner, let him learn regular conventions 1st. 2. I can safely assume that over 99% of beginners are taught ASCII conventions and how to use them in code. My entire country is a testament to that as i know how programming is taught here and there's nothing wrong with that. 3. THe spirit of the question was to get the basics right. Let's not confuse the OP

Comment: Why use different conventions when you don't need to?  (Agreed you often need to - but this wasn't such a case.)

Comment: @Shreyans Sherh thank you for understanding.  It's true I haven't learned some of the syntax mentioned in the comments.  But my codes work now, thank you very much!  I'll remember to alway initialize everything from now on.